Why is the destination register encoded in a different place for MUL(S) on ARM?
This question is about the instructions MUL and MULS (hereinafter, just Multiply), which were introduced with the ARM2, and the encoding of the register operands. In this context, Rd refers to the destination register where results are stored, and Rn refers to one of the source registers (the others include Rm, Rs, etc)
If we compare with all other instructions, Multiply has Rd and Rn swapped around in the encoding, as compared with other instructions.

The first row in the table shows the Data processing/PSR Transfer instructions (This includes AND, ADD, CMP and so on), where the Rn is encoded by bits 19..16 and the destination register is encoded by bits 15..12. This is the pattern shared by Swap instructions and Halfword transfer instructions as well, and is similar to what the co-processor instructions do as well.
But the Multiply instruction has Rd encoded by bits 19..16, and Rn encoded by bits 15..12, which means they're swapped! (Not that I know much about ASIC design, but what I'm picturing is that the hardware now needs an extra step to figure out which register to latch the result(s) to)
I'm looking for some kind of rationale. Has this matter been reverse-engineered or documented somewhere by ARM or a third party? Or, is there something I'm missing?

This is speculative, so I'm commenting rather than answering, but I think early ARM devices used an iterative multiply process; one of the source registers would be loaded before the operation and held in a register separate from the ALU, while the ALU operations would operate on the destination register and the other source operand.  The ALU operand routing was probably more time-critical than the destination routing, so having the destination configurable to mirror one of the source operands was probably easier than having the ALU be able to receive data from the selected destination.

ARM's tech writers seem confused about it as well.  Eg, this 1996 ref manual, page 3-22 shows 19..16 as Rn and 15..12 as Rd; page 3-58, shows bits 19-16 as Rn (and 15-12 as should be 0), or this 2005 ref manual, page A3-35, table A3-4 which again shows 19..16 as Rn and 15..12 as Rd.

@KelvinSherlock Why would someone believe that bits 15..12 need to be 0? Is MUL somehow limited to working with R0 on early versions or something?

@OmarandLorraine The Acorn assembler in BBC BASIC V (comes with Arthur 1.2) knows about MUL working with other registers, so it's unlikely that any ARM chip was limited to R0 for Rn. Looks more like a thinko to me than anything else.

MUL is Rd = Rm*Rs, where Rd is 19..16, Rm is 3..0, and Rs is 11..8. There is no Rn/15..12.

To expand on @KelvinSherlock's comment a little - MLA and MUL are almost the same, but MLA uses a fourth register, Rn, as an extra source. - MUL does Rd = Rm * Rs, while MLA does Rd = Rn + Rm * Rs
The only rule in both cases is that Rd cannot be the same as Rm, since Rd is used as a partial result accumulator, and Rm is read repeatedly during the multiply.

Partial answer:
To my knowledge, the ARM2 has not currently been reverse engineered, but the ARM1 has been. In particular, as Ken Shirriff describes, it does use microcode (though order of magnitude less microcode than comparable processors, so it still qualifies as RISC).
There don't seem to be that many differences between ARM2 and ARM1 (archive link, original is currently not reachable), so it's reasonable to assume the ARM2 used very similar microcode.
Looking at various instruction timings online for MUL and MULS (though it is not entirely clear if they refer to an actual ARM2 or a later architecture) strongly suggest that multiplication is executed in multiple instructions in microcode, in a loop that had early termination conditions (as the timing depends on the actual value of one operand).
The description of multiplication in the above link also mentions a 2-bit Booth multiplier, which again means a microcode loop.
So the reason for the swap very likely is that it was easier to write microcode for multiple multiplication steps when Rn and Rd are swapped, and/or that this resulted in shorter and faster microcode.
To verify that, one would have to look at the actual microcode for multiplication of the ARM2, which would require a decapped and scanned ARM2 chip. So I guess until someone does this, the answer has to remain unverified.

Huh, a Booth's multiplier. I wouldn't have thought that. I would have used the already present barrel shifter, priority encoder and adder.

@OmarandLorraine apparently that was too slow...

@OmarandLorraine: A Booth's multiplier will process two bits per iteration, and will handle runs of leading ones just as efficiently as leading zeroes.  Even if a priority encoder would be faster for some operands, it would be slower for others.

@OmarandLorraine: Incidentally, if the description of the Booth multiplier is too intimidating, the essence is that instead of iteratively looking at one bit of shifting multiplcand X to decide whether or not to add the other multiplicand Y to a shifting partial product, one looks at overlapping sets of three bits to decide whether to add Y, subtract Y, add 2Y, subtract 2Y, or add nothing, avoiding the need to ever add or subtract 3Y.
